Driver suggested for B4352 not recognized in 22.04
My Asus desktop uses Broadcom 4352 chip for WiFi.  It has always worked for 20.04.  Recently installed new 22.04, and Broadcom STA drivers selected automatically (same as used in 20.04) but the WiFi adapter is not recognized, so there is no WiFi.  Numerous suggestions have failed, including b43 drivers, but those are blacklisted.
How is it possible to configure WiFi to work?  The b43 appears to be blacklisted by bcmwl.  No dynamic module appears to be loaded, but I don't really know which module to look for...
lspci:
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

lshw:
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: Ethernet Connection (2) I218-V
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: eno1
             version: 00
             serial: 08:62:66:30:ce:30
             size: 1Gbit/s
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=6.5.0-27-generic duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.10.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
             resources: irq:27 memory:f7f00000-f7f1ffff memory:f7f3c000-f7f3cfff ioport:f080(size=32)
...
           *-network UNCLAIMED
                description: Network controller
                product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 03
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:f7e00000-f7e07fff memory:f7c00000-f7dfffff


May want to look at results for mokutil --sb in terminal

I don't know what I should find in 'mokutil'.  It just says 'secure boot enabled'.

I see that the bcmwl source code is on the disk, but I've no idea what else to do with it.  There is no 'bcmwl' kernel loaded that I find.  Something has occurred with it, as it was the agent to blacklist the other drivers.

There is no module named 'bcmwl' in /lib/modules/...  I don't know if that is the correct name.  Where is it supposed to be installed?  The Ubuntu installer certainly didn't do it...

'sudo modprobe wl' reports:
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Key was rejected by service

Just ran
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt -y install build-essential
sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
per some advice on Ubuntu.  Result is another failure:
Building for 6.5.0-27-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 6.5.0-27-generic
Failed to enroll new keys
Failed to set MokTimeout
Done.
wl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.

Original module

No original module exists within this kernel


Installation

Installing to /lib/modules/6.5.0-27-generic/updates/dkms/




depmod...
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Key was rejected by service
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-27-generic
smichaelsmith@Asus-U22:~$

Have you disabled Secure Boot in the BIOS settings?

Thanks Jeremy31!

The Bios had "Windows OS mode" set.  The setting for Secure Boot was fixed ON and not accessible.  I switched to "Other OS" and when rebooted, Wifi was working!  So relieved!
